# Prove that if $ab \equiv cd \pmod{n}$ and $b \equiv d \pmod n$ and $\gcd(b, n) = 1$ then $a \equiv c \pmod n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

> Prove that if $ab \equiv cd \pmod{n}$ and $b \equiv d \pmod n$ and $\gcd(b, n) = 1$ then $a \equiv c \pmod n$.

From this we know that $\gcd(d, n) = 1$. I can't derive anything else. Please help. Is there some basic theorem which points to this? Can we cut out $b$ and $d$ in $ab \equiv cd \pmod{n}$ if we know they leave the same residues $\pmod n$?

Thanks.

Comment: The gcd condition implies that $b$ (hence also $d$) is invertible

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How do you define invertible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma.** If $xz\equiv yz \pmod{n}$, then $x\equiv y\pmod {\frac{n}{d}}$, where $d=\gcd(n,z)$.

*Proof.* $n|z(y-x)\implies \frac{n}{d}\big| \frac{z}{d}(y-x)$. Hence, $\gcd(\frac{n}{d},\frac{z}{d})=1$, which implies that $\frac{n}{d}\big|(y-x)$.//

Now, since $\gcd(b,n)=\gcd(d,n)=1$, we can use the above lemma as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
ab\equiv cd\pmod{n}\text{ and }b\equiv d\pmod {n} &\implies abd\equiv cbd\pmod {n}\\
&\implies ab\equiv cb\pmod {n}\qquad\text{by the lemma}\\
&\implies a\equiv c\pmod{n}\qquad\text{by the lemma}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}{}{}$ BTW our rep is equal.

Comment: :-) I'm happy!!

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I think it is fun solving problems like this using Bezout's lemma: since ${\rm gcd}(b,n) = 1$ there exist integers $x$ and $y$ with 
$$\tag 1 bx + ny = 1.$$
Since $ab \equiv cd \bmod n$ there is an integer $s$ such that $$\tag 2 ab = cd + ns$$ and since $b \equiv d \bmod n$ there is an integer $t$ such that $$\tag 3 b = d + nt.$$

Multiply line (1) by $a$ and $c$ individually to get 
\begin{align} \tag 4 abx + any &= a \\ \tag 5 bcx + cny &= c.\end{align}

Multiply line (2) by $x$ to get $$\tag 6 abx = cdx + nsx$$ and multiply line (3) by $cx$ to get $$\tag 7 bcx = cdx + cntx.$$ Now subtract (7) from (6) to get $$abx - bcx = n(sx - ntx)$$ and use this result to subtract (5) from (4):
$$n(sx - ntx) + n(ay - cy) = a-c.$$ Thus $n$ divides $a-c$ as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I went for an easier approach using congruences. We have: $ab\equiv cd\;(mod\;n)$ and $b \equiv d \; (mod\;n)$. We deduce the following: $n|ab-cd$ and $n|b-d$.
My first approach was to combine both statements and try to obtain $n|b-c$, but I couldn't find it. Look at the mistake:

From both $n|ab-cd$ and $n|b-d$, we can obtain first, $n|a(b-d)$ (cause it is a multiple) and then mix both into: $n|ab-cd-ab+ad$, reordering, $n|d(a-c)$. But here, we cannot use the last hypothesis that says $gcd(b,n)=1$ because we don't have any $b$. In other words, if we can find a different but same method expression, we can use the hypothesis and find that $n|a-c$, our objective.

Therefore, I decided to multiply by $c$ the first expression instead of $a$ (what we did before). That way, $n|c(b-d)$, and mix it into: $n|ab-cd-cb+cd=ab-cb \to n|b(a-c)$. Now, we are legitimated to use the last hypothesis ($gcd(b,n)=1$), so have the following: $n|a-c$, and easily find what we want: $a\equiv b \;(mod\; n)$.